# How to change the available values of a <Select> on input from another <Select>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[Not jQuery] I have two Selects's and a list of elements and wish to map the available options on the second Select based on the current value of the first select

```
<Select options={sources} defaultValue={sources[0]} onChange={() => {
                // change value of select below
            }}/>

<Select options={mediums} defaultValue={mediums[0]} name="mediumSelect"/>
```

I'm not sure how to do this without jquery and currently interning at a company that does not use jquery at all. Any input is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer is to set some piece of state and use it in the second component:

```
<Select options={sources} defaultValue={sources[0]} onChange={(e) => {
  this.setState({
    value1: e.target.value
  });
}}/>

// modify whatever you need based on `this.state.value1`
<Select options={mediums} defaultValue={mediums[0]} name="mediumSelect"/>
```

There are many different ways to do this, depending on if you're using redux, etc. But this should get you started. You should definitely do some reading about the [basics of react & forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this...
Here, listen on change of source select component and update the options array of the second input, don't forget to check if an element already exists in an array on not

```
       <Select  
          options={sources}
          value={this.state.selectedSource}
          onChange={evt => {
            this.setState({
              mediums: [...this.state.mediums, evt.target.value],
              selectedSource: evt.target.value
            });
          }}
        />
        <Select
          options={sources}
          value={this.state.selectedMediums}
          onChange={evt => {
            this.setState({
              selectedMediums: evt.target.value
            });
          }}
        />
```

With Native HTML elements

```
    <select
      value={this.state.selectedSource}
      onChange={evt => {
        this.setState({
          mediums: [...this.state.mediums, evt.target.value],
          selectedSource: evt.target.value
        });
      }}
    >
      {this.state.sources.map(value => {
        return (
          <option value={value} key={value}>
            {value}
          </option>
        );
      })}
    </select>
    <select
      value={this.state.selectedMediums}
      onChange={evt => {
        this.setState({
          selectedMediums: evt.target.value
        });
      }}
    >
      {this.state.mediums.map(value => {
        return (
          <option value={value} key={value}>
            {value}
          </option>
        );
      })}
    </select>
```

Comment: Your answer is not following the provided code. The question shows `<Select>` (not the native HTML component) with the attribute `options` on it. Your answer is using the native HTML `<select>` with a map function to generate multiple `<option>` tags.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro I thought its a common understanding if you are using custom component then anybody can change it accordingly but  now I have added both approaches so that novice person can also understand it easily

Comment: @Harshkurra I see your point, but I think the assumption is: If the person is asking here in SO and posting the code, they probably need an answer following their code, instead of a more overall concept. Thanks for updating your answer. Upvoted now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the value of first Select to your component state, then apply your custom own logic for the second Select values according to first Select value

```js
const sources = ["A", "B"];
const mediumsA = ["C", "D"];
const mediumsB = ["E", "F"];
class Todo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {     
      selectedMedium: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      selectedMedium: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    //your logic to your mediums var
    const mediums = this.state.selectedMedium === "B" ? mediumsB : mediumsA;

    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          options={sources}
          defaultValue={sources[0]}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <Select options={mediums} defaultValue="" name="mediumSelect" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}



const Select = ({ options, onChange })=> {
    return (
      <select onChange={onChange}>
        {options.map(data => {
          return <option>{data}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
    );
};


ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using reactjs.
Although with any framework I think it is possible to follow these steps:

1. Make `mediums` variable is global variable
2. in the event onChange of first Select assigns a value to `mediums`
3. render the second Select based on the variable `mediums`

Comment: You are correct to say that this would probably work to any framework, however, the point of using a framework is to take advantage of its exclusive features or resources. So, even though this is not a wrong answer, it is not the most appropriate to the React world :)